# Serialize knockout viewmodel, ideas?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to serialize the viewmodel to json, but I only get `undefined` on the `ko.toJSON(PageViewModel)` part. Any idea?

```
function PageViewModel() {

    //Properties
    this.Name = ko.observable();
    this.Title = ko.observable();
    this.Language = ko.observable();

    //Seo
    this.SEOKeywords = ko.observable();
    this.SEODescription = ko.observable();
    this.SEOIndexPage = ko.observable();
    this.SEOGeoPositionLatitude = ko.observable();
    this.SEOGeoPositionLongitude = ko.observable();
    this.SEOGeoPositionPlaceName = ko.observable();
    this.SEOGeoPositionRegion = ko.observable();

}
```

```
ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel());
window.loadFirebugConsole;
console.log(ko.toJSON(PageViewModel));
```

Thanks
Mick

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to serialize function instead of object. Update your code to this:

```
var vm = new PageViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
window.loadFirebugConsole;
console.log(ko.toJSON(vm));
```

Comment: Thanks, you right about that:) I changed that now, but i still got 'undefined'.

Comment: Are you sure? I gor empty object - not undefined and this is because you don't have any data filled in your object. See fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EPyvW/

Comment: And if you define VM at the window level like window.vm = new PageViewModel() then you can use the console in Chrome to view it's contents at any time. Very helpful when trying to figure out data issues.